# Is it possible to signup in Facebook without an email id?

Tags: facebook, email

I have a question about Facebook signup. I need to know the possibility of signing up with any mobile phone number or any other way without giving an email id. It is important because I am developing a fb app in which users email is a must. Or is it possible to signup with an email id later remove that id from account?

Comment: Sorry, how is it related to anykind of coding or programing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The mobile registration page allows for users to signup without an email address: http://touch.facebook.com/r.php

Comment: It seems to require an email now.

Comment: Now, email is no longer required. Facebook registration even in desktop requires only Email OR Phone.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to sign up for Facebook without an email: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-email.