# Unable to retrieve email address from Facebook API

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am getting a null pointer exception while getting an email address from Facebook API on Android 3.0.

The code generating the exception is below:

```
LoginButton authButton;
authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
// set permission list, Don't forget to add email
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));
authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                     Exception exception) {
        showToast("Inside Call");
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            showToast("Inside Session");
            System.out.println("facebook Access Token"
                               + session.getAccessToken());
            fbToken = session.getAccessToken();
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                          new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                                                      Response response) {
                                                  if (user != null) {
                                                      String email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          });
        }
    }
});
```

The code was working previously - I might have made a mistake while integrating code.

Comment: your code seems totally working, did you try with different user?

Comment: does your app have the user_email permission?

Comment: @OnurA. It was working.. Now i think there is some problem with adding read permissions... i am still wondering what could be the issue...

Comment: @VinceFR i added the email permission -authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));

Comment: if it'S working with different user than the previous user whose email address rturns nulls might have hiden it, in which case you have nothing to do, user have to enable email in private settings

Comment: @OnurA. I read the permission documentation And found that my session was opened..SO i need to reset the permission.. Now its working.. - This method is only meaningful if called before the session is open. If this is called after the session is opened, and the list of permissions passed in is not a subset of the permissions granted during the authorization, it will log an error.

Comment: Sometimes the user has been registered using only the mobile number and they dont have an email address. So checkif thats the case.

Check this link out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195556/is-it-possible-to-signup-in-facebook-without-an-email-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the user email from the GraphUser Object by using the property.

```
 user.getProperty("email").toString()
```

It works for me.Hoping it will also work for you.