# Table structure for Authentication using Facebook and Google Plus?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, google-plus

I am making an Android Application where the users can log in either through Facebook or Google Plus. Right now I am not providing my own login.

From Facebook, I am retrieving the following fields.

- email
- id
- name

From Google Plus, I am retrieving the following fields.

- email
- imageUrl
- name

---

Now I need a table schema to store the user credentials whether the user logs in through Facebook or Google Plus.
Problem is that in Google Plus, I can get emailId which will be unique for every user and I can make it as a primary key. but in facebook, even though I am getting email, it is not necessary that I will get email from each user. The user may have not registered an emailId. So what should be userid if the user logs in through facebook. Should I keep id as the userid. 
Right now, I can think of the following fields

- userid (primary key )
- name
- email
- imageUrl
- mode ( facebook or google plus)

Comment: Why wont u get email from FB? How can a person create a FB account without email?

Comment: it is possible to create FB without email.  Instead of email one can signup through mobile number. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195556/is-it-possible-to-signup-in-facebook-without-an-email-id

Answer (score 0):

For getting any public information of an user from Facebook, you can use:

```
    public void getProfileInformation() {
    try {

        JSONObject profile = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me"));
        Log.e("Profile", "" + profile);
        fb_mUserId = profile.getString("id");
        fb_verified = profile.getBoolean("verified");
        fb_mUserToken = facebook.getAccessToken();
        fb_mUserName = profile.getString("name");
        fb_mUserEmail = profile.getString("email");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Log.e("FaceBook_Profile", "" + fb_mUserId + "\n"
                        + fb_mUserToken + "\n" + fb_mUserName + "\n"
                        + fb_mUserEmail);
            }
        });

    } catch (FacebookError e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```